# Custom Loss Lunction MXNet for Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions

I'm new here and was wondering if anyone would help me out with creating a custom loss function in R using the MXNet package.

I was hoping to improve on my current model by trying to make it cost sensitive through a loss function. I had a look online and it all seems confusing to me and hoped that maybe someone can make sense of it for me?

Many thanks